# Creating palette image on the fly for remap behind : palette is not reset each time

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick-convert

I'm using Rmagick (Ruby on Rails gem to use ImageMagick).
I'm building a tool to remap images with some specific color palette.

As inputs, I have :

An image (.png or .jpg)
A array of color hex codes.

I have an error when I'm creating my palette on the fly.

I've built this script to create the palette with color hex codes in order to use it during the remap :

```
colorpallet = MiniMagick::Image.new("palette_tmp.png")
colors.each do |color_item|
color = MiniMagick::Image.new("color_tmp.png")
color.run_command('convert', '-size', '1x1', "xc:#{color_item}", color.path)
colorpallet.run_command('convert', '+append', colorpallet.path, color.path, colorpallet.path)
end
```

When I run my script, I get this error :

> magick convert +append palette_tmp.png color_tmp.png palette_tmp.png failed with status: 1 and error:
> convert: unable to open image 'palette_tmp.png': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3569.

Yet, palette_tmp.png is existing...

Then, i use the remap operator like this :

```
remap_sketch.run_command('convert', url, '-dither', 'FloydSteinberg', '-remap', colorpallet.path, remap_sketch.path)
```

I have two questions :

Do you know why I have this error about "No such file or directory" ?

Is there a way to do a remap without generating a color palette file on the fly ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know or use Ruby, but I do use **ImageMagick**. I think you want to use `-remap` to map to a specific set of colours but without generating an image, or maybe without writing to disk to define the palette.

Hopefully you can adapt from the command-line to Ruby. The command-line can accept a palette in a text form, so I guess you can create that text form in Ruby. Say you want to map to 3 colours, pure red, pure lime (green) and pure blue. You would make your palette with:

```
magick xc:red xc:lime xc:blue +append palette.png
```

Then you'd map an image to that palette with:

```
magick input.jpg -remap palette.png
```

However, it works with text too, so you can make your palette like this:

```
magick xc:red xc:lime xc:blue -depth 8 palette.txt
```

That will look like this:

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 3,1,0,255,srgb
0,0: (255,0,0)  #FF0000  red
1,0: (0,255,0)  #00FF00  lime
2,0: (0,0,255)  #0000FF  blue
```

and you can use it just the same:

```
magick input.png -remap palette.txt result.png
```

But, getting to the point, you don't need to use an actual text file, you can generate it on `stdin` on the fly and ImageMagick will use it without requiring it to be a file on disk:

```
echo "# ImageMagick pixel enumeration...." | magick input.jpg -remap - result.jpg
```

---

You can also simplify the file down to something like:

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 3,1,0,255,srgb
0,0: (255,0,0)
1,0: (0,255,0)
2,0: (0,0,255)
```